# What is involved in making entry of text into a web app into all javascript?

Tags: javascript

What I am talking about is similar to what Google Docs did with the word processor. I want to be able to enter text without using a `<textarea>` but the javascript hard coding it in. How would you do this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible but You can you an modify textarea itself using CSS so the user will not feel that this is actually text area is. I believe that this is what Google docs are doing. Just good CSS work.

Comment: really? I don't think so. I think the old google docs was that way but now it is all javascript. Another example of one that is definitely like this is studyblue.com's notes sections. As you enter text each line is put into a seperate div and you can do things like lists.

Comment: I think so. There is no other option to type text inside any other HTML control except TexArea, I beleive they perform various JavaScript manipulations with this textarea, but by the end of the day the text is written inside textarea.

Comment: hmm... ok, I guess they are just using some pretty crazy javascript inside the text area

Comment: see this post : http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2010/05/whats-different-about-new-google-docs.html especially the second part